# No signal received from dialog

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, signals-slots

```
class Table : public QTableWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  signals:
  void sigStatusMsg( const QString& msg );
};

//----------------------------------------

class ShowTableDlg : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public slots:
  void slotStatusMsg( const QString& msg );

  signals:
  void sigStatusMsg( const QString& msg );
}

void ShowTableDlg::slotStatusMsg( const QString& msg )
{
  m_statusBar->showMessage( msg );
  emit sigStatusMsg( msg );
}

//------------------------------------------

class TopDialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public slots:
  void slotCallShowTable();
  void slotStatusMsg( const QString& msg );
}

void TopDialog::slotCallShowTable()
{
  ShowTableDlg* dlg { new ShowTableDlg };
  connect( dlg, &ShowTableDlg::sigStatusMsg, 
           this, &TopDialog::slotStatusMsg );
  dlg->exec();
}
```

The ShowTableDlg shows the message properly, the slot in TopDialog is never
reached. Maybe I'm too blind or too stupid. The original code is far more longer, but I reduced it to this small excerpt, which shows the principal structure. There is no error or warning during compilation or execution.

Where or what is my mistake?

Comment: Your code is difficult to track .. anyway the problem likely is because of where your connect statement is placed .. you seem to emit the signal (sigStatusMsg( msg )  BEFORE the connect() is made .. try to place the connect () in TopDialog constructor or make sure the connect() is executed before the emit()

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked a function call in my constructor. Yes. the messages are sent before the connection is established.